# Total internal reflection in single mode fiber

Tags: fiber-optics

As only one mode (parallel to the fiber axis) propagates through a single mode fiber, so does total internal reflection occur inside a single mode fiber and how? And how the light is guided in single mode fiber

Comment: You have to solve Maxwell's equations for the radius dependent optical density of the fiber and treat it as an inhomogeneous waveguide.

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you very much sir for your reply. but is the ray theory is applicable for single mode fiber as it is applicable for multimode fiber.

Comment: No, you can not solve the single mode fiber with the same level of ray theory as the multimode fiber.

Comment: @CuriousOne again thanks a lot sir. but sir then how to describe the guiding principle of single mode fiber in terms of total internal reflection.

Comment: You can't. Total internal reflection is a principle that works when the geometry of the optical system is large compared to the wavelength. That is not the case for a single mode fiber, which makes it necessary to use Maxwell's equations. 8-10.5um is approx. 6-10 wavelengths at the typical wavelengths with which these fibers are being used. that's too little for a geometric optic approximation.